# make default language without language code at url

Tags: magento-1.8

I have two languages on my magento. I would like to make one of them the default language without the /el/ language code.

So, the domain.com will load the default language (Greek) and the domain.com/fr/ will load the french version of my magento shop.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the default store view to the one with Greek language. Configuration>manage stores then select the store name and change default store view to the one with Greek launguage

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the /el/ is still remaining. This solution, loads by default the greek version. It isn't  remove the the language code from url